# Error creating a new Native-Application (Android) in Visual Studio

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and included Visual c++ cross-platform for Android. The installation was successful. After installation I created a new project Native-Activity Application (Android).

Upon building the project to execute it in an emulator, I encountered the following:

Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin\ant.bat" debug -Dout.final.file="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Projects\Exp\Android3\Android3\Android3.Packaging\ARM\Debug\Android3.apk"" exited with code 1.   Android3.Packaging  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets    378

Why am I getting the error? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had gotten a very similar error when I created a new Native Android Application using Visual Studio 2015. It turned out in my case that there were additional errors in the output tab saying that it could not find android-19. So what I did was used visual studio 2015 "Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager" to install Android 4.42 (API 19) and I was able to build my solution.